# Are ground fault currents shown as RMS or Peak in GFCIs?

Tags: circuit-breaker

When a GFCI (Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter) states that it trips for example at 30 mA, is this value RMS or Peak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMS

The current shown will be RMS

Comment: how can it be RMS of a pulse?

Comment: They don’t operate faster than 1/60 of a second, right?  That is one cycle at 60 Hz.  Not sure, but [this document](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a031781.pdf) may be of use to you.